# Добавить уменьшение счетчика голосов

Tags: javascript, vue.js, функции, методы

Ниже блок HTML и метод с работающим увеличением счетчика. Надо добавить к нему уменьшение. А как в голову не приходит.

```
     <div class="media-right">
       <span class="icon is-small" @click="upvote(post.id)">
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
        <strong class="has-text-info">{{post.votes}}</strong>
       </span>
     </div>
```

```
    props: ['post', 'posts'],
    methods: {
        upvote(postId) {
            const post = this.posts.find(
                post => post.id === postId);
            post.votes++;
    }
```

Comment: `post.votes--;`

Comment: лентяй вы, вот и всё

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос из разряда "напишите код за меня"... У вас есть готовый код. Нужно просто поменять плюсы на минусы и добавить новую кнопку...

И было бы неплохо использовать camelCase для названий методов и переменных. (upVote, downVote и т.д.)

```html
<div class="media-right">
  <span class="icon is-small" @click="upvote(post.id)">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </span>
  <strong class="has-text-info">{{post.votes}}</strong>
  <span class="icon is-small" @click="downvote(post.id)">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

```js
props: ['post', 'posts'],
methods: {
  upvote(postId) {
    const post = this.posts.find(
    post => post.id === postId);
    post.votes++;
  },
  downvote() {
    const post = this.posts.find(
    post => post.id === postId);
    post.votes--;
  }
}
```